# Cannot compile Vitamio demo

Tags: android, compilation, undefined, android-videoview, vitamio

I successfully installed the Zi library and the VitamioBundle, but I cannot achieve to compile the VitamioDemo example.

Eclipse says that the methods setVideoPath, setVideoQuality, setMediaController and setVideoLayout are undefined for the type VideoView.
This strange because the VitamioBundle is correctly linked to the project as a library. Any idea?

Something else : why do I have to link the whole VitamionBundle as a library? Should not the vitamio.jar file be enough?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna  use VitamioDemo, Please checkout [VitamioBundle V3.0](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/v3.0). Not master

Comment: Thanks. They already answered me by email, and yes, with v3 it works fine.